# Failing to connect to mysocket.sock, connection refused (gunicorn, nginx)

Tags: nginx, django, gunicorn

Full error:

```
2018/03/12 04:59:08 [error] 1562#1562: *1787 connect() to unix:/home/mik
e/movingcollage/movingcollage.sock failed (111: Connection refused) whil
e connecting to upstream, client: 107.205.110.154, server: movingcollage
.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/mike/movin
gcollage/movingcollage.sock:/", host: "movingcollage.com"
```

My config is ok, this used to work; I pulled some new application code and am now getting a 502 bad gateway error (before I pulled the application code the site worked fine). I already did `service gunicorn restart` and `systemctl restart gunicorn` and am still getting the 502 bad gateway error. Can anyone help?

This is a django project, for what it's worth.

Gunicorn config:

```
description "Gunicorn application server handling movingcollage"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
setuid user
setgid www-data
chdir /home/mike/movingcollage

exec movingcollageenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/user/myproject/movingcollage.sock movingcollage.wsgi:application
```

Edit: I've changed the last line to `exec movingcollageenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/mike/movingcollage/movingcollage.sock movingcollage.wsgi:application` and it still doesn't work. Note that the previous line used to work fine

Comment: What are you `bind`ing to in your gunicorn configuration?

Comment: Posted my config in the question @MichaelHampton

Comment: Those paths are definitely different. You should fix that.